# Is it safe to nest parallel streams?

Tags: java, java-8, parallel-processing, java-stream

I've seen that early on in java 8's lifetime, it would cause deadlocks to nest parallel streams, and I believe this has been fixed. Are they any other issues that could arise? I understand that nesting parallelstreams will not lead to as high of a performance as otherwise, but it still seems to improve my speed by about 50% (reduces runtime from 11 minutes -> 5.5 minutes) .

Of course, if it leads to issues I would rather just do it slower, but searching for nested parallelstreams is returning the early 1.8 issues rather than any current ones.

Here's some simplified example code (it's for making relative references in list of 80k objects be more easily transferred across systems. In the actual code there are some more operations and a more detailed try/catch for exceptions) -

```
LinkSystem(List<Obj>objList,String property){

objList.parallelstream
.filter(obj -> obj.getAttribute.equals(property))
.forEach(f->
 {
 try { Optional<Obj>MysteryObj = objList.parallelStream()
.filter(z->z.getAttribute2.equals(f.getAttribute3)
.findAny();
f.setAttribute4(z.MysteryObj.get().getID()); 
});
 } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Comment: Are you asking if deadlocks can occur in general or just in the specified code?

Comment: Well, not deadlocks - more other issues.  I believe the deadlock issue was fixed. I think I would have seen one by now if it still could? 

More if the given code could cause concurrency issues, race conditions, useless processing. (I am curious about nesting parallestreams in general as well, but it's for this specific code that I'm currently concerned).

Comment: Intuitively I don't see problems. Looks like you are doing read-only stuff. If you want to figure out problems yourself, you may want to research how parallel streams actually work. A deadlock or race condition is not something that randomly happens like in quantum physics; there are causes for it, e.g. wrong synchronization. You can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62670686/12323248) answer for a slightly deeper explanation about what parallel streams do and keep going from there.

Comment: The key term is *time complexity*. Your nested iteration has *quadratic* time complexity and dividing it by the constant number of CPU cores (in the best case) doesn’t change that. Creating a map from attribute2 to obj first and using it in a second iteration has *linear* time complexity and will run significantly faster for large data sets, even with sequential streams. I guess, a few seconds instead of your five minutes…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, Java 8 never had deadlock issues with a straight-forwardly nested usage like yours.

But you are using the wrong approach anyway. Nesting two iterations leads to *quadratic time complexity* and dividing it by the constant number of CPU cores (in the best case) doesn’t change that.

Instead, create a `Map` from attribute2 values to the corresponding `Obj` first and use this map in a second iteration. Iterating two times consecutively still has *linear time complexity* and will run significantly faster for large data sets, even with sequential streams.

```
Map<TypeOfYourAttribute,Obj> attr2Lookup = objList.stream()
    .filter(obj -> obj.getAttribute().equals(property))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Obj::getAttribute2, Function.identity()));

objList.stream()
//  .filter(obj -> obj.getAttribute().equals(property))
    .forEach(f -> {
        Obj z = attr2Lookup.get(f.getAttribute3());
        if(z != null) {
            f.setAttribute4(z.getID());
        }
    });
```

Note that objects that didn’t pass the filter in the first iteration won’t appear in the map, so handling `null` responses from `attr2Lookup.get(…)` is sufficient and the second iteration doesn’t need the filter. There is a small optimization opportunity here. If the majority of the objects are expected to pass the filter, omit the `filter` step in the second iteration. But if most objects are rejected by the filter, it’s more efficient to do the filter here, because string comparison is cheaper than a hash lookup.

Without the `filter` in the second step, you could also use `forEach` directly on the `List`, omitting the stream overhead, but using a stream opens the opportunity to use a parallel stream here.

You may experiment with these opportunities, I think, turning the first step to parallel will never have a benefit, but the second might have. In either case, I expect every combination to perform better than your nested iteration approach for 80k elements.